# Android 5 Media Browser API examples

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media

Per Android Dev Docs,

> Android 5.0 introduces the ability for apps to browse the media
>   content library of another app, through the new android.media.browse
>   API.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Media

I tried looking onto the examples folder of SDK but didn't find any examples related to Media browser. Can someone point to a good sample?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the reference guide for [`android.media.browse`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/browse/package-summary.html).

The sources for `MediaBrowser.java` can be found in `AOSP` tree as [here](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/browse/MediaBrowser.java).

Some examples:

[`MusicService.java`](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/developers/demos/MusicDemo/src/main/java/com/example/android/musicservicedemo/MusicService.java)

[`MediaBrowserService.java`](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/media/java/android/service/media/MediaBrowserService.java)

[`BrowserService`](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/tests/MusicServiceDemo/src/com/example/android/musicservicedemo/BrowserService.java)